# Outlook & Exchange: More unread emails are shown in inbox than are actually inside the inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

In Outlook inbox shows "inbox 10", but when you go to the inbox there's only 5 unread mails. So...where are the 5 others?

Comment: Have you got conversations grouped?

Comment: No, I do not have it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it could be related with following reasons:

1. Unread status sync incorrectly with web mail

Mentioned in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/79a0ea7c-8ec5-4c4f-97bd-019436e908fc/there-is-no-unread-mail-in-inbox-folder-but-it-marked-there-has-one-unread-item?forum=outlook), we can log on web mail and mark these emails as read.

2. check if sort or filter is applied to inbox so that some unread emails are hidden.

We can try to start Outlook with /cleanviews switch to check if the problem is related to corrupt view. To do this, exit Outlook, press Windows key + R to open the Run command, type outlook.exe /cleanviews and press Enter.

3. Data file corrupted

[Recreate local OST file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253) and let Outlook client re-sync items from server.